# singleton fields not visible in debbuger under Instance method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Consider typical singleton class

```
public class Singleton{

    private static Singleton _instance;
    private static Singleton ThisInstance {
        get => _instance;
        set => _instance = value;
    }

    public static Instance()
    {
        lock(_lockThis) {
            return ThisInstance ?? (ThisInstance = new Singleton());
        }
    }

    private Singleton(){}

    public bool Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The problem is when I try to debug anything simple, for instance, command predicate:

```
public bool CommandPredicate(object obj){
    return Singleton.Instance().Field1 == true &&
           Singleton.Instance().Field2 > 10;
}
```

Values of **Field1** and **Field2** follow after **Instance()** so they are invisible. When you move cursor over those fields there is nothing.

The only work-around I found by far is to assign Instance to a variable, like this:

```
public bool CommandPredicate(object obj){
    var a = Singleton.Instance(); 
    return a.Field1 == true &&
           a.Field2 > 10;
}
```

Then you can see all values of **a** in debbuger.

Is there any standard and elegant approach for viewing singleton fields?

Comment: it sounds like the real difficulty here is that `Instance` is a method rather than a property; you can probably just *change that*, but frankly I'm not sure why you don't just init the instance in a cctor and forget about it, i.e. `public static Singleton Instance {get; } = new Singleton();`

Comment: member declaraton even statics need to be inside a class yours is currently outside !?!?!

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton). It exposes the instance as a property rather than a method, which will be "hoverable" in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Instance()` method to a property - the debugger will show the values then.

You may want to consider creating the instance in a static constructor to prevent any multithreading issues:

```
public class Singleton{

    private static Singleton _instance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton Instance { 
        get => _instance;
    }
...
```